# Shutting down connection pool data source with Dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard, hikaricp

I am using Dropwizard with HikariCP connection pool, but I guess this could be about using any connection pool. How do I configure Dropwizard to call shutdown() method of HikariCP datasource whenever application shuts down? Is it even possible?

HikariCP FAQ states that Spring or other IOC containers make it possible, but I'm not using DI frameworks at this point, just Dropwizard.

Comment: This [Google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/UP1krCq--cA)  might be useful.

Comment: Thanks Brett! You're right, this is the relevant docs section: https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#managed-objects And thanks for HikariCP, most excellent!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `Managed` interface: http://www.dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#managed-objects